# What's the best way to draw a chain of arcs with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to specify a list of indices and have the result be a bunch of semicircular arcs with filled circles as the endpoints.  That is, given the lists [0,3,1,2], [0,1,2,4,3], and [0,1,3,6,8,5,2,4,7,9,10], I'd like to generate pictures like the following (upper left, upper right, and bottom, respectively):

[image: Three examples]

What's the best way to do this in TikZ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the sequence always starts with zero then you can make it draw a consecutive arc hopping with a loop. The arc size depends on the difference of the current index and the next index on the array.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={fill,inner sep=1pt,circle}]
\draw (0,0) node[dot]{}
\foreach\x[remember=\x as\xi(initially 0),evaluate={\xa = \x-\xi > 0?180:0;}]
   in {1,3,6,8,5,2,4,7,9,10}{arc (\xa:180-\xa:{abs(\x-\xi)}) node[dot]{}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

if you change the array to `{3,1,2}`

[image]

and then `{1,2,4,3}`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em]
  \foreach \n in {1,...,4}
    \coordinate (chain-\n) at (\n-1,0)
                (chain-\n) node[circle,draw,fill,inner sep=0pt] {};
  \foreach \from/\to in {1/4,2/3,2/4}
    \draw (chain-\from) to[out=90,in=90,looseness=1.7] (chain-\to);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em]
  \foreach \n in {1,...,11}
    \coordinate (chain-\n) at (\n-1,0)
                (chain-\n) node[circle,draw,fill,inner sep=0pt] {};
  \foreach \from/\to in {1/2,2/4,3/5,3/6,4/7,5/8,6/9,7/9,8/10,10/11}
    \draw (chain-\from) to[out=90,in=90,looseness=1.7] (chain-\to);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question, but I think it's a good starting point.